# Rails simple_form attribute required mark (*)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, required

I am using Simple Form in my app and I'd like to remove the `*` to indicate an attribute is required on all of my forms (existing and those yet to be created).

I have tried to set in `simple_form.rb`:

```
  # Whether attributes are required by default (or not). Default is true.
  config.required_by_default = false
```

And I've tried to modify `simple_form.en.yml`:

```
   required:
      text: 'required'
      mark: ''  # <------ tried setting this to blank.
```

I know I can set `:required => false` on each field, but I want to clean up the views & set it once.

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the value?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Setting the `simple_form.required.mask` to `''` should work if you restarted the server.

But you can remove it changing the the configuration:

```
# config.label_text = proc { |label, required| "#{required} #{label}" }
```

to

```
config.label_text = proc { |label, required| "#{label}" }
```

Comment: I changed mine to:    config.label_text = lambda { |label, required| required.present? ? "<strong>#{label}</strong>" : "#{label}" }

Comment: check the rails 4 answer below before you use this

Answer (score 20):

You can also do

```
simple_form_for @model, :defaults => {:required => false}
```

Answer (score 6):

on Rails 4 just remove the "required" word

```
 config.label_text = lambda { |label, required, explicit_label| "#{required} #{label}" }
```

so it should be

```
config.label_text = lambda { |label, required, explicit_label| "#{} #{label}" }
```

Validation still works!

Answer (score 0):

just

`# Whether attributes are required by default (or not). Default is true.
  config.required_by_default = false`

and restart your rails server. Then it works.

Comment: Having a validator on a attribute [overrides](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/v3.1.0/lib/simple_form/helpers/required.rb#L10-18) this setting.