# Rails Simple_Form Gem -remove required (*) prepend

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out how to use Simple Form. I want to remove that "*" prepended to required fields. I still want validations, but I don't want that styling.

I have tried each of the suggestions in this post: 
[Rails simple_form attribute required mark (*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592536/rails-simple-form-attribute-required-mark)

I have also tried all of the suggestions in the post marked as a duplicate in the comment below. None of these work. Simple Form is not simple.

I'm using rails with simple form and bootstrap.

I have currently got this in my initialiser.rb

```
  config.label_text = lambda { |label, required, explicit_label| "#{} #{label}" }
```

I have removed "mark: "*" from the simple_form.yml file.
I have restarted the server. These incredibly frustrating * are still showing.

How do you get rid of the * on required fields?

Comment: No - the suggestions are the same as the post I tagged. These aren't wroking

Comment: Except that as you said in your comment below, when you **actually** followed the advice (not commenting out the line, just making the value `""`) then it did actually work.

Comment: no - actually - that just makes the field blank - it doesnt switch it off

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to config/initializers/simple_form.rb

Find this line (around line 100)

#### How the label text should be generated altogether with the required text.

Then uncommented the below line.

```
config.label_text = lambda { |label, required, explicit_label| "#{required} #{label}" }
```

Remove `#{required}` completely so you have

```
config.label_text = lambda { |label, required, explicit_label| "#{label}" }
```

**Alternatively** you can go to config/locales/simple_form.en.yml

Find `mark: '*'` (around line 7)
and remove the Asterisk so you have `mark: ''`

Restart your server after either instance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, your suggestion for the initialiser is what I currently have. I changed the yml file to delete the mark. I restarted the server. They are still there

Comment: Actually, I commented out the entire line. Those * go away when you keep the line but make the mark blank

Comment: The first option does nothing - just in case others are facing the same teeth grindingly annoying problem

Comment: I've tested both ways and they both work but it may be dependent on the versions your running or another configuration. Glad you got it working though.

Comment: It doesn't work with simple_form-3.2.0

Comment: @Mel the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52799060/how-to-remove-asterisk-in-required-fields-when-using-simple-form) indicates you may have t adjust a simple_form_bootstrap initializer as well