# how to remove asterisk in required fields when using simple form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

In the simple_form initializer there is this line

```
  # How the label text should be generated altogether with the required text.
  # config.label_text = lambda { |label, required, explicit_label| "#{required} #{label}" }
```

I removed the comment and changed it to

```
  # How the label text should be generated altogether with the required text.
   config.label_text = lambda { |label, required, explicit_label| "#{label}" }
```

But this doesnt affect the asterisk in the required fields. The * is still present in the labels. How can i remove the asterisk in the required field?

UPDATE:

I am uploading the image. The askterisk is present even after server restart.

[image]

Comment: Have you restarted server after this?

Comment: @Gabbar yes the asterisk is still there after server restart.

Answer (score 1):

ok so i forgot when generating simple form i used bootstrap flag. That created a second initializer file called simple_form_bootstrap.rb. So the change had to be made in this file. After the change in this file, it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a hacky fix is to just do it through css:

```
abbr[title="required"] {
  display: none;
}
```

replace abbrwith whatever selector selects the *